# How can I move bower libraries in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, bower, .net-core

In my `wwwroot` folder I have two subfolders called `lib` and `lib_bower`. My `lib_bower` folder is setup in my `.bowerrc` file like so:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib_bower"
}
```

When I restore `bower packages` I'm left with this:

[image]

I'd like to move the entire `dist` folder from `bootstrap` into my `lib` folder when I build if the files are not found. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gulp` task runner to move bootstrap folder into lib folder.

Configuration code(gulpfile.js):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

var paths = {};
paths.webroot = "wwwroot/";
paths.bowerSrc = "./wwwroot/lib_bower/";
paths.lib = paths.webroot + "lib/";

gulp.task("copy-bootstrap", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.bowerSrc + '/bootstrap/dist/**/*.*', { base: paths.bowerSrc + '/bootstrap/dist/' })
         .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib + '/bootstrap/'));
});
```

Then right click `gulpfile.js`, select `Task Runner Explorer`, run the `copy-bootstrap` task or set `Bindings` to `Before Build` .