# ASP Core copy folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

How can copy folder to another directory automatically when I build project? I need to copy from app/images to wwwroot/images. I think I can do it in project.json "buildOptions" section, but I don't know how.

Comment: Assuming you want to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but i want to be able open my project in other ide

Comment: You can use gulp. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38259425/5426333

Comment: It works, I can accept this as answer if nobody know how do it without npm (gulp, grunt, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use gulp/grunt tasks you can do something like this in your project.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postcompile": ["xcopy app/images wwwroot/images"]
}
```

This is telling visual studio to run "xcopy" command after compile/build your project.

You also have other options like precompile, prepublish, and so on.