# Copy html file in wwwroot

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I've created empty asp.net core application. after that I install angular2 application there using angular-cli. Now I faced a problem. on startup it looks in `wwwroot` folder to find index.html. But my folder structure is:

[image]

what can I do?

In tsconfig I've changed `"outDir": "../wwwroot/",`  but it only adds js files there

Comment: Have you checked the [typescript documentation on setting up a ASP.NET Core application with Angular2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html)? Maybe it helpes solving your problem...

Comment: You can use `gulp` to move it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259425/how-can-i-move-bower-libraries-in-asp-net-core/38260664#38260664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you're doing that you don't need to run angular application using f5. All you need to do is:

1. Right click on `package.json`
2. Click on `Task runner explorer`
3. Under `Defaults` tab right click `start` and Run

After that your application will run on `localhost:4200`

Answer (score 0):

Their is angular-cli.json file in that you need to change the `"outDir":"wwwroot",`
after you run can this command `ng build -prod`